# How to check if hot-swap or hot-plug are activated on my Linux machine

Tags: ubuntu, scsi, hot-plug

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 64-bit on a PowerEdge 2900. My current setup has two 300GB disks (no RAID), but I want migrate the system to three new 600GB disks. I'm trying to connect the new disks, make a RAID5 array, and copy my partitions to the new RAID, but i'm not sure if the server has hot-plug support or, in particular, if it's activated.

Looking at the system I get:

```
admin@host:~$ lsscsi -v
[4:0:0:0]    disk    HITACHI  HUS151414VLS300  A48B  /dev/sda
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/4:0:0:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/host4/port-4:0/end_device-4:0/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0]
[4:0:1:0]    disk    HITACHI  HUS151414VLS300  A48B  /dev/sdb
  dir: /sys/bus/scsi/devices/4:0:1:0  [/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:08.0/host4/port-4:1/end_device-4:1/target4:0:1/4:0:1:0]

admin@host:~$ lspci | grep '02:08.0'
02:08.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS1068 PCI-X Fusion-MPT SAS (rev 01)
```

[LSI SAS 1068](http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS1068.aspx) has hot-swap support according to the description, but I'm not sure, and I can't power-off the system for migration or check in bios. I'm afraid to just connect a disk in case it damages the controller or the disk itself, so I need a way to check if hot-plug/hot-swap is activated in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper SAS/SATA connectors are hot plug safe, so as long as you are using those connectors both for data *and* power ( *not* the usual PC [molex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex) power connector ) then you won't hurt anything plugging them in.